# How to enforce Update with rowlock while Inner join nolock?

Tags: sql-server, locking

```
UPDATE PS --WITH(ROWLOCK) optionA
SET NewColumn = 
(CASE
    WHEN (PS.ColumnA IS NOT NULL AND PS.ColumnA > 0) THEN PS.ColumnA
    ELSE TableB.SomeColumn END
)
FROM MainTable AS PS WITH(ROWLOCK) -- optionB
INNER JOIN  TableA WITH(NOLOCK) ON TableA.ID = PS.TableAID
INNER JOIN TableB WITH(NOLOCK) ON TableB.ID = TableA.TableBID
```

Is the above statement the correct way to make sure `MainTable` being `ROWLOCK` while inner join other table with `NOLOCK`?

Seems like both `optionA` and `optionB` can be executed successfully and hence I'm not sure whether both are correct with the intended `rowlock`?

Since `MainTable` will be having 100 million records, while running the update script, is there any way i can check to make sure `MainTable` being rowlock?

Comment: Are you saying that you would like to check that the update statement will lock as expected before execution?

Answer (score 0):

Both options are functionally the same, though I find most code would be written with `WITH(ROWLOCK)` after `UPDATE PS` (Option A), as update statements don't always include a from clause.

As for checking that `WITH (ROWLOCK)` is working as expected while the update statement is running, I would say that there is no need. You have specified a locking hint and this will override the usual process for selecting the granularity of a lock.

Comment: By placing `WITH(ROWLOCK)` after `UPDATE PS` OR at the `FROM` part doesnt throw any errors and both are executable. Both are correct and really lock as expected?

Comment: Quite right, several years of seeing it written only one way has had an effect, I've edited my answer.